# How to apply jquery for particular class

Tags: php, jquery

I am showing images in list with having next and previous button.

I have use this jquery in for loop so that it can more than one.

```
list1:

Prev <ul><li> img1 img2 img3....</li></ul> Next

list2:

Prev <ul><li> img1 img2 img3....</li></ul> Next
```

if i have three different image list on same page if i click on next Or prev of 1st list then its apply  for all list.

how can i apply it for that particular list to move Next and prev.

I have used the code from ths link:http://css-plus.com/2010/09/create-your-own-jquery-image-slider/

i have used folloeing code:
    Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Gallery
    if(jQuery(".gallery").length){

        // Declare variables
        var totalImages = jQuery(".gallery > li").length, 
            imageWidth = jQuery(".gallery > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery(".gallery-wrap").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

        jQuery(".gallery").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
            if(jQuery(".gallery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery(".gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery(".gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function(){
            if(jQuery(".gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery(".gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery(".gallery").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

});




 Html and php:
    <?php foreach($records as $row) :?>

     <div id="gallery-wrap">
        <ul id="gallery" class="gallery">
                <?php foreach($row['images'] as $image) :?> 
                 <li> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $image['img']; ?> /></a>
                </li> 
                <?php endforeach ;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
       <div id="gallery-controls" class="gallery-controls">
        <a href="#" id="gallery-prev" >Prev</a>
        <a href="#" id="gallery-next" >Next</a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
```

Comment: Do you want the images in a particular list to move next or previous?

Comment: @mabus44:if i click next for first list then only it move the next image of list one. now for my code it apply for all list if i click on next/prev of any list

Comment: In that case, try giving each <li> element a class then identify for which <li> has been clicked, then move the img in that list accordingly...

Comment: @bipen:Html also provided.

Answer (score 1):

ok first of all....

1) IDs should always be unique... but  in your case  you have elements with same ID since it is in loop.. so either change it and makeit unique OR you can change it to class in your HTML code...

```
 <div class="gallery-wrap">
 -----^^---- change to class...
```

2) since you are using class , all your ID selector i.e `#` should be replaced by class selector `.` in your jquery code.

```
 jQuery(".gallery-prev").click(function(){
 --------^------ here
```

changes in your

**HTML**

```
<div class="galleryDisplayBlock"> //add new div
  <div class="gallery-wrap">
    <ul class="gallery">
            <?php foreach($row['images'] as $image) :?> 
             <li> 
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $image['img']; ?> /></a>
            </li> 
            <?php endforeach ;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <div class="gallery-controls">
    <a href="#" class="gallery-prev" >Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="gallery-next" >Next</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
    jQuery(".gallery-prev").click(function(){
        var thisGallery=jQuery(this).parent();
        if(thisGallery.find(".gallery").position().left < 0 && !thisGallery.find(".gallery").is(":animated")){
            thisGallery.find(".gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery(".gallery-next").click(function(){
            var thisGallery=jQuery(this).parent(); 
            if(thisGallery.find(".gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !thisGallery.find(".gallery").is(":animated")){
            thisGallery.find(".gallery").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: :i have tried this,till on click of next  of any list images of all list are moving.